# Duplicate data while using a unique key

Tags: mysql, database, unique-key

For my table I've defined a unique index on `activity_id`-`actor_id`-`end_date`;

```
mysql> show keys from sg_activity_property;
+----------------------+------------+-------------+--------------+----------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table                | Non_unique | Key_name    | Seq_in_index | Column_name          | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+----------------------+------------+-------------+--------------+----------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| sg_activity_property |          0 | PRIMARY     |            1 | activity_property_id | A         |         506 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| sg_activity_property |          0 | activity_id |            1 | activity_id          | A         |        NULL |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| sg_activity_property |          0 | activity_id |            2 | actor_id             | A         |        NULL |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| sg_activity_property |          0 | activity_id |            3 | end_date             | A         |        NULL |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
+----------------------+------------+-------------+--------------+----------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So, how can this data exist??

```
mysql> SELECT activity_property_id, activity_id, actor_id, start_date, end_date FROM  `sg_activity_property` WHERE  `activity_id` =250;
+----------------------+-------------+----------+---------------------+----------+
| activity_property_id | activity_id | actor_id | start_date          | end_date |
+----------------------+-------------+----------+---------------------+----------+
|                  509 |         250 |        8 | 2011-09-02 11:10:50 | NULL     |
|                  510 |         250 |        8 | 2011-09-02 11:10:50 | NULL     |
+----------------------+-------------+----------+---------------------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Edit:** here's the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE sg_activity_property`:

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE sg_activity_property;
+----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table                | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
+----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| sg_activity_property | CREATE TABLE `sg_activity_property` (
  `activity_property_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `activity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `actor_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `importance` enum('very low','low','normal','high','very high') NOT NULL default 'normal',
  `urgency` enum('!','!!') default NULL,
  `completed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `start_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `end_date` datetime default NULL,
  `review_frequency` int(11) NOT NULL default '1',
  `review_frequency_unit` enum('day','week','month','quarter','year') NOT NULL default 'week',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`activity_property_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `activity_id` (`activity_id`,`actor_id`,`end_date`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=511 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+----------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.19 sec)
```

Comment: Can we please get the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE sg_activity_property`?

Comment: Added the output to the post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because of the `NULL` on end_date,
technically NULL <> EMPTY, or any value, is just a placeholder where value is missing

so, change it to NOT NULL should fix

**PS:** when you doing alter

```
alter table sg_activity_property 
modify column end_date datetime not null
default '0000-00-00 00:00:00';
```

this will fail, because mysql will attempt to convert the NULL to `0000-00-00 00:00:00`,
in order to fix this, you can either assign some random value to it first,
or just simply remove one of the duplicate

Comment: Unfortunately, I need `NULL` here because I use it to find the 'current' entry (`WHERE end_date IS NULL`)

Comment: you can always convert it to `WHERE end_date=0`

Comment: Will that perform equally well?

Comment: Really? I'm going to alter it right away then. Bummer that I have to edit all my queries though... (:

Answer (score 2):

This is the expected behavior. Check the MySQL documentation:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table.html

> A UNIQUE index creates a constraint such that all values in the index
>   must be distinct. An error occurs if you try to add a new row with a
>   key value that matches an existing row. This constraint does not apply
>   to NULL values except for the BDB storage engine. For other engines, a
>   UNIQUE index permits multiple NULL values for columns that can contain
>   NULL.

Comment: Thank you for this usefull comment. I would have never expected NULL to be 'skipped' in MySQL indexes!

Answer (score 0):

You have NULL values in end_date.

A NULL value is an undefined value, therefore two
NULL values are not the same.

Comment: Two NULL values are NOT the same?? That completely baffles me.